# Python: using pandas groupby to reduce the dimensionality of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe, let's call it df, I have data that looks like

```
serial gps_dt lat long dist
1      25Mar  x1  y1   Nan
1      26Mar  x2  y2   0.01
1      27Mar  x3  y3   1.25  (assume this is the 5th occurrence < 160)
2      24Mar  x4  y5   Nan
2      25Mar  x5  y5   2.1
2      26Mar  x6  y6   1.01
2      27Mar  x7  y7   175.2
2      28Mar  x8  y8   179.3  (assume this is the 5th occurrence > 160)
```

And this continues. I already have a series, let's call it `check` that tells me if `serial[i] == serial[i+1]`. What I want to do now is when they are equal, construct a new dataframe that contains `serial, gps_dt_first, gps_dt_last, avg_lat, avg_long` under the conditions `hdist < 160` and we have at least 5 occurrences within this radius. If `hdist > 160`, I want to construct another group if and only if the next 5 occurrences are within 160 of the first one greater than 160.

For example, the output would look something like:

```
serial gps_dt_first gps_dt_last avg_lat avg_long
1      25Mar        27Mar       avg_x   avg_y
2      27Mar        28Mar       avg_x   avg_y
```

I am looking at the [group by](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) documentation in Pandas. The data is already in `serial, gps_dt` order from SAS. Do I need to still do `df.groupby(['serial', 'gps_dt'])`?

Once the df is grouped, if needed, my thought of the code is (more of a pseudo code outline):

```
if check == true and hdist < 160 and 5 or more occurrences (how to count the occurrences):
    result['serial'] = df.serial (first in serial; how to extract)
    result['gps_dt_first'] = df.gps_dt (first in gps_dt)
    result['gps_dt_last'] = df.gps_dt (last in gps_dt)
    result['avg_lat'] = df.lat.mean() (only for the subset of serial meeting criteria)
    result['avg_long'] = df.long.mean() (same here)
else if check == true and hdist > 160 and 5 or more occurrences;
    do same as above
else:
    delete
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are already reading the docs for `groupby`, you could do what the following sections explain:

1. [Iterate over each element you got from `groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups);
2. [Perform one or more `aggregate` operations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) (including applying chained operations, or different operation depending on column);